# php if inside or outside the function

Tags: php, function, if-statement, scope

I often get in this situation where I have an if statement and I can't deside where to put it. **As a wrapper around the function or inside the function?**

Is one of the two solutions here better than the other? If so, why?

**Solution 1**

```
function one($something) {
    if( $something === 'yes') {
        two();
    }
}

function two() {
    echo 'ok';
}

one('yes');
```

**Solution 2**

```
function one($something) {
    two($something);
}

function two($something) {
    if( $something === 'yes') {
        echo 'ok';
    }
}

one('yes');
```

Comment: Solution 2 appears to be completely pointless in your example. Without a real example, the answer here is really just "it depends".

Comment: checking before calling function its better

Comment: unless "one" is supposed to do something else, in your second example it is just pointless to have such a function, it's just redundant in my opinion. As rjdown pointed above, though, you should provide us a clearer example in order to understand what is the real point of the question.

Comment: @devpro Alright. Why?

Comment: because, if conditions not full fill no need to call any function. technically you can use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to choose between your two variants - one should be used if you need it to be recursive. If you do not need it to be recursive, you can use both of them.